# Sending a command in the windows command prompt that terminates after a certain time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using a batch script to create a short functional test for technicians at my work which would normally require them to send several commands back-to-back themselves.

There is a command that brings up an image on the test device, but the command hangs until you press ctr+c. When doing everything manual that's fine but I don't want the technicians to do that during the script because they might accidentally exit out of the whole thing.

Is there a way to make it so the script can stop that command and move on the next line in the script? Something like a timeout on the command? Or a key press that just stops the command but doesn't close the script?

Code sample:

```
echo "Booting Device..."
adb start device
timeout 40

adb shell load_image yosimite.png
timeout 5
```

Comment: Do you want to kill this task after some time or is pressing Ctrl+C still part of its normal operation?

Comment: Yes there are, but you'll need to provide some code to help us understand you environment. For now it is difficult to help.

Comment: @Anders, Well, Ctr+C is how it was intended to be stopped but if a tech uses Ctrl+C in the script and accidentally presses y then they have to start the script over. I'd be willing to kill the task somehow.

Gerhard, it is a batch script. I can paste some code into the problem but it's basically one line that is the issue.